# SpringMVC controller can not deal with the request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

1. I follow the instruction from the book "Spring in action" in SprinvMVC chapter
2. When i run the tomcat server and try the demo it return error like:

   HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

   Type Status Report

   Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqzxc.png)

3. I using macOS , tomcat9 , Intellij 2017.1 , jdk 1.9
   and here is my code.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spitter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spitter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spitter.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!--static resources getting-->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources"/>

<!--use annotations to create the mapping between-->
<!-- url and class deal with request(Controller) -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!--scan the component and auto regist as bean-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc"/>

<!--Use this bean to map the jsp file according to the name return by Controller-->
<!--It will automatically add the prefix and suffix to the name string-->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

controller:

```
package com.springmvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
* Created by xwh on 29/3/2017.
*/
@Controller
  public class HomeController {
//    public static final int DEAFAULT_SPITTLES_PER_PAGE = 25;


public HomeController() {
    System.out.println("-------HomeController init-------");
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String showHomePage() {

    System.out.println("-------showHomePage Method show-------");


    return "home";
  }
}
```

And here is my directory pic.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEQKP.png)

Comment: try @RequestMapping("/") => @RequestMapping("/Spring_no_2/")

Comment: try url localhost:8080/ without the "Spring_no_2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your contextConfigLocation file is spitter-servlet.xml?
In your web.xml file, you defined the context config file is applicationContext.xml. It means your configs in spitter.xml is not used.
try change the contextConfigLocation to /WEB-INF/spitter-servlet.xml